# Software center not opening

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software Center empty “No usefulness from server” “no username in config file”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128244/software-center-empty-no-usefulness-from-server-no-username-in-config-file)

I can't open the software center. Is there anything I can do to get it to start?

```
$ software-center
2012-09-07 18:45:04,349 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 410, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2012-09-07 18:45:04,349 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on :1.128:/com/ubuntu/Softwarecenter: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
2012-09-07 18:45:29,406 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2012-09-07 18:45:29,409 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2012-09-07 18:45:29,822 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2012-09-07 18:45:29,973 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2012-09-07 18:45:29,991 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Killed
```